# Core Data: Predicate that Returns Objects of Another Entity

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have two entities in my data model: `Details` and `Lookup`. I need find all `Details` objects related to a specific `Lookup` object that has specific attribute value and then return those `Details` objects via a fetched results controller.

My NSManagedObjectSubclasses:

```
@interface Details : NSManagedObject {
@privateI 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * owner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * introduction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * created;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * modified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;


@interface Lookup : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * search_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * search_phrase;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* searchResults;
```

I need to find a `Lookup` object based on its `search_phrase` attribute and then get all the related `Details` objects and return those in a fetched results controller.

I think I have to search for the `Lookup` object first, then walk the NSSet of Detail objects but I do not know how to return those in the NSFetchedResultsController.

I've tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"search_phrase = %@", self.searchPhrase];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Lookup" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"search_phrase" ascending:NO];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Searches"];
```

I have a request that finds the right `Lookup` object but I don't know how to get the related `Detail` objects from the fetched results controller.

Comment: You original question was voted down because it was unclear and incomplete. It was hard for anyone to figure out what you needed. I have edited it with the additional information to make a more useful question.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I will try harder next time to make my self clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have a reciprocal relationship defined between `Details` and `Lookup` but just a one-way `Lookup` to `Details`. You need to add a relationship to both the data model entity running from `Detail` to `Lookup` and have it set has the recipocal of `Lookup.searchResults` and your `Detail` class needs a property something like:

```
@property (nonAtomic,retain) Lookup *lookup;
```

Having a reciprocal relationship lets you find `Detail` objects by starting with a `Lookup` object and lets you find a `Lookup` object starting with a `Detail` object.

If you want you tableview to display a list of `Detail` objects, then you need to configure the fetched results controller's fetch request to fetch against the `Detail` entity. As a rule of thumb, you always set the fetch request entity to the entity whose objects you wish to display in the tableview.

The predicate likewise will be run against the `Detail` entity so you need a predicate that evaluates against a keypath that starts with a property of the `Detail` entity. In this case, we want all `Details` objects whose related `Lookup` object has a `search_phase` attribute equalling a provide value. So:

```
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lookup.search_phrase==%@", self.searchPhrase];
```

Now setup your fetch request thusly:

```
  NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *detailsEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
  [fetch setEntity:detailsEntity];
  [fetch setPredicate:p];
  //.. set up a sort however you want the details to appear in the tableview
```

Give this fetch to your NSFetchedResultsController and it will return the `Detail` objects you are looking for.

In summary:

- Always use reciprocal relationships in a data model so you can have flexibility.
- When using a fetched results controller, set the entity of the fetch request to the entity whose objects you wish to appear in the tableview.

Comment: An excellent answer that makes this very clear to me...THANKS!  I will see to implementing this and let you know the outcome, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without some of your sample code or even the actual relationships, but here goes:

- Perform your initial filter on table A. This gives you a set of results containing a number of objects.
- Query table B with your filter and `AND #Put name of the relationship here# IN (the results of 1)`

Something else to add though, you should stop thinking about core data as a relational database. It's an object graph. Core data may or may not use different tables to store the data. What you should be concerned with are the objects and their relationships.

If I understand correctly you don't really want a 1 to many, but a many to many. 
You will then be able to perform both queries at once with a query for B objects:

```
A.your.a.query == 'What you're querying for' AND your.b.query == here
```

Comment: I have tried this: predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@ AND searchResults IN %@", self.resource, lsrm.searchResults]; but I get an error stating Invalid predicate: nil RHS

Comment: having no luck with this at all, any one want to throw me a bone please?  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@ AND searchResults IN %@", self.resource, lsrm.searchResults] where lsrm.searchResults is an NSSet from Lookup object.  Now I get an error stating this: reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@ AND SELF IN %@", self.resource, lsrm.searchResults]; is the way.  I found this answer from a colleague but accepted your answer as it pointed me in the right direction ;-)